# Database in iOS application: Sqlite vs XML + XPath?

Tags: ios, xml, sqlite, xpath, nsxmlparser

my app needs to read some data exported from a SQL database. In addition to reading, the app should also query the database in order to find relations between different data.
Potentially, the amount of data can be very large.
Of course, everything should be responsive and not impact negatively of the user experience.

Here is my doubt: I was going to export the database in XML format and run queries by using XPath but I'm not 100% sure that this approach is going to be efficient enough, especially if the number of records in the database is around thousands.

What can you guys tell me about the efficiency and performance of XPath in iOS? Is that a good solution for large XML database?

Would Sqlite be a better and more efficient approach? By using Sqlite, am I risking to make my app heavy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definately should use SQLite over XML in iOS apps. I would recommend the best wrapper for such a database: https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb
With FMDB + making queries in background threads the performance of app shouldn't be affected at all, even with big DB.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look at the framework... seems to be exactly what I am looking for! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Many of my iOS applications use data stored in SQLite databases. I have good trust in SQLite databases.

Some of my databases have more than 30000 elements in tables and applications make complex queries such as filtering/grouping by criteria. It is quite fast.

The best way to create your SQLite data is to export as CSV from your original databases and to import data in a new SQLite database.
[You can find an example here.](http://phoenixdesign.fr/tutoriels/base-de-donnees/creation-base-sqlite)

Comment: Thank you very much! Hearing that SQLite allows to achieve good performance makes me happy :-)